# Cruising from Canada to Alaska

Tags: visas, esta, cruising

We are flying to Canada and staying with friends, but during our stay we are cruising to Alaska and back. Do I need an ESTA?

Comment: When you say "cruising", what, exactly, do you mean? Taking a boat? Car? Bus? Motorcycle? Airplane? What nationality are you? Passport? Citizenship? All of this matters in answering your question.

Comment: @CGCampbell it also probably matters whether the cruise, if by boat, is on a private craft or a scheduled cruise line.  I suppose, however, that it is safe to assume that OP is a national of a visa waiver program country.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are a national of a Visa Waiver Program country.

If your cruise to Alaska is on a private vessel, or a commercial cruise operated by someone other than an "approved carrier," you are not eligible to use the VWP.  You must apply for a visa.

If your cruise to Alaska is a commercial cruise operated by an approved carrier, you must have authorization through ESTA.

If for some reason you are using "cruise" to refer to overland travel, then you do not require ESTA.

Source: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country,-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico

Comment: And [some advice](https://ask.pocruises.com/help/PO/before-you-sail/visa/ESTA_Application_Address) on what to fill in for that ESTA.